# Magmi error when importing Dataflow export

Tags: magmi

Troubleshooting Magmi by way of the least-common-denominator, I exported a framework CSV from one Magento site with Dataflow, then immediately re-imported it with Magmi on another Magento site. I got an error:

CSV Datasource v1.2 - warning: line 1 , wrong column number : 25 found over 1, line skipped

I'm guessing there is something in the site's Magmi setup that I can't quite see, that is controlling any other imports? This second site already uses Magmi to import products on a nightly basis. I see the error above using both its established profile, and any other profile I create.

Answer (score 0):

Magmi, by default, is set to process CSV files with each column enclosed in a double quote `"`.

If you look under the `Configure Current Profile` section, you'll find a filed labeled `CSV Enclosure`, with a double quote populated.

On the other hand, Magento exports the CSV files without the double quote wrappers.  Try removing the double quote from the `CSV Enclosure` field in Magmi, then saving the profile.  Do a test run and see if that works.

If this doesn't work, you can import the file into Excel and resave the file using double quotes.  The method that works for me goes as follows:

1. Open Excel (create a blank spreadsheet)
2. Go to the `Data` tab in Excel, click the `From Text` button.
3. Open your CSV exported from Magento
4. Choose `Delimited` and click `Next`
5. Under `Delimiters`, select `Comma`.  Click Next
6. On the `Data Preview` section, highlight all of the columns (Hold shift and select the farthest column on the right).
7. Choose `Text` under `Column data format`
8. Click Finish

After you verified all of your data is correct in the spreadsheet, you'll have to export it to wrap all of the cell values in double-quotes.  To do this, follow this tutorial:
http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/export_excel_csvs_with_double_quotes

After the file is saved, upload it to your `var/import` directory, set Magmi to use `"` as the `CSV Enclosure`, and try running the import.